# Setting AWS Lambda as Principal in Permission Policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-iam

I have a very specific AWS Lambda function that I want to make the Principal to AWS Secret Manager permission policy so it can retrieve secrets.

I want to specifically give this permission only to my Lambda. I created a role and assigned that role to the policy.

However, I want to be able to write the Principal in explicitly (for learning and to know what it does on first sight).

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Lambda Get Secret File",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "secretsmanager:GetSecretValue",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXXX:role/My-Lambda"    
            },
            "Resource": "arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-west-2:XXXXXX:secret:My-Secret"
        }
    ]
}
```

This won't be allowed. 
What is the way to write this in?

Everything I see is for Lambda to rotate, I don't want to rotate.

Comment: So you've created a secret and you've attached a resource policy allowing GetSecretValue from a named IAM role and your Lambda function executes with that IAM role but it can't access the secret? Or you failed at an earlier step and could not actually configure the resource policy? It's not clear what "this won't be allowed" means.

Comment: @jarmod when I try to submit this in the policy editor in AWS console. "Principal won't be allowed" is the actual issue that comes up. came up with a link to the allowed policies but not sure where I went wrong. It's not very descriptive which is why I came here.

Comment: Are you sure that you are not trying to enter this policy into IAM (which would be invalid)? As far as I can see, the Secrets Manager console does not allow you to configure resource policies. You have to use the awscli or an SDK to do it. Where are you submitting this policy?

Comment: awww that might be up. I made this policy in the policy manager. I was trying to find some way to have my lambda download a secret without bloated code. But I guess I have to use the `boto` library and codify pulling it in. I just noticed a lot of AWS can be set up to talk to each other for automation purposes so I was trying to go that route as much as possible.

Comment: You can use the awscli (aws secretsmanager put-resource-policy) or boto3/python (SecretsManager.Client.put_resource_policy) to configure resource policies for Secrets Manager.

Comment: You may find this answer helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77270028/12326605

Answer (score 15):

It's important when working with AWS identity/permissions to understand that there are [two types of policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_identity-vs-resource.html):

1. identity-based policies (you attach these to identities)
2. resource-based policies (you attach these to resources)

Identity-based policies are attached to an IAM user, group, or role. These policies let you specify what that identity can do. These policies *cannot* have a `Principal` element because the principal that the policy applies to is implicitly the IAM principal presenting the credentials.

Resource-based policies are attached to an AWS resource, such as an S3 bucket, KMS key, or Lambda function. These policies specify who can access the given resource and what they can do. Most commonly, you will see these with S3 buckets but they can also be associated with other resource types. These policies *must* have a `Principal` element in order to identify to whom the policy statement applies.

A resource-based policy can serve as an additional layer of security, allowing a resource owner to explicitly deny certain IAM principals from accessing a resource, even if those IAM principals have permission.

Typically, either an identity-based policy or a resource-based policy can permit access to a given resource (you would not need to permit access in both policies). Per the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_evaluation-logic.html#policy-eval-basics):

> If an action is allowed by an identity-based policy, a resource-based policy, or both, then AWS allows the action. An explicit deny in either of these policies overrides the allow.

There are a small number of situations in which both an identity-based policy and a corresponding resource-based policy must allow an action for it to be permitted. Use of KMS keys for encryption/decryption is one example of this.

In your case, you should be configuring a resource-based policy for the Secrets Manager secret, controlling who has access to the secret.

I was able to add the following policy to a Secrets Manager secret (I saved this policy in a file named `mysecret.json`:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "secureme",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "secretsmanager:GetSecretValue",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/mylambdarole"
      },
      "Resource": "arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-east-1:123456789012:secret:mysecret-xyz"
    }
  ]
}
```

You can't use the AWS Console to apply this policy to the secret, as far as I know, but you can use the awscli or an SDK. I used the awscli, a follows:

```
aws secretsmanager put-resource-policy \
    --secret-id mysecret \
    --resource-policy file://mysecret.json
```

Comment: The above policy has a Syntax error, Please try correcting it

Comment: {
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "secureme",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "secretsmanager:GetSecretValue",
      "Principal":{
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/mylambdarole"
      },
      "Resource": "arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-east-1:123456789012:secret:mysecret-xyz"
    }
  ]
}

Comment: I'm a bit confused by the presence of the `"Resource"` element in the policy. Since it's a resource policy, which you're associating to a single, fixed, resource, I don't think you're supposed to have a `"Resource"` element in there. When you make the CLI call, there's a parameter entered `--secret-id mysecret` - isn't that the resource to which you're associating the policy? In which case, does it make sense to have this resource in the policy itself: `arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-east-1:123456789012:secret:mysecret-xyz`?

Comment: @ColmBhandal thanks for the valuable comments, will review and update as needed shortly.

Answer (score 3):

In the AWS IAM User Guide, there is a chapter about [AWS JSON Policy Elements: Principal](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_principal.html). If you scroll down on the page, there is a paragraph about **AWS service**:

> A service principal is an identifier that is used to grant permissions to a service. The identifier includes the long version of a service name, and is usually in the following format:
>
> long_service-name.amazonaws.com

Consequently, since it is a Lambda function you are dealing with, the principal element should read:

```
"Principal": {
  "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"
},
```

Comment: but that's not a specific Lambda service, that's just all Lambda services, no?

Comment: Can you try using the Condition operator: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_condition_operators.html#Conditions_ARN?

Comment: Service linked roles are not [generally available for AWS Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_aws-services-that-work-with-iam.html).

Comment: What  krishna_mee2004 notes seems to be correct, a resource based policy is not sufficient for the lambda to access a secret, an identity based policy is needed

Comment: From what I can see, the principal `lambda.amazonaws.com` is the AWS Lambda service itself, before it assumes any execution role for any particular function. The only place I can think of where that principal is referenced in practice is in the trust policy of some particular lambda function's execution role, basically saying, "Hey, Lambda service, you can assume this role to run my function." Once the role is assumed and the function is executing, I believe the principal is no longer `lambda.amazonaws.com`, but it is the lambda execution role that was assumed by Lambda.