# No identity-based policy allows the secretsmanager:GetSecretValue action error in AWS, even though I have created a valid policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a simple AWS application that runs a lambda function and I am attempting to fetch a secrets object where I have stored some auth tokens.

When I invoke my function even though I have created a resource policy that specifies the ARN and the function that I want to run, I keep getting an error message saying that I am not authorised to access the resource.

I will post my policy below but with some hardcoded values for security purposes:

```json
{
  "Version" : "2012-10-17",
  "Statement" : [ {
     "Action" : "secretsmanager:GetSecretValue",
     "Resource" : "arn:aws:secretsmanager:Region:AccountId:secret:SecretName-123123",
     "Effect" : "Allow",
     "Principal" : {
      "Service" : "secretsmanager.amazonaws.com"
    }
  } ]
}
```

The policy is saved correctly and there are no syntax errors. Is there anything else that I need to include ?

Initially there was a syntax error that prevented me from saving the policy. The issue was solved by adding the "Principal" property. However the access denied error is still there.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Setting AWS Lambda as Principal in Permission Policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56192833/setting-aws-lambda-as-principal-in-permission-policy)

Comment: @paolo will have a look, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using *resource-based* policy to attach a permissions policy to an AWS Secrets Manager secret, you need to specify the `ARN` of your Lambda function as the `Principle` in the resource-based policy to your secret.

```json
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::AccountId:role/LamdaRoleToAccessSecrets"
      },
      "Action": "secretsmanager:GetSecretValue",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:secretsmanager:Region:AccountId:secret:SecretName-123123"
    }
  ]
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes this worked thank you.